# Display just the 12 Hour Time format from an ISO 8601 Timestamp

Tags: ios

So I want to display just the time that is passed from our server in a label in my iOS App but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to set up the right NSDateFormatter. So for example I get this timestamp from the Server in this format: 2013-02-27T18:15:00-0800, and I basically want to display "10:15 AM" in a label but so far I haven't had any luck. I tried this below:

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
            NSString *newTime = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:timeDate];
            NSLog(@"the new time is: %@", newTime);
```

But the output shows my time as 18:15 PM.

I've been looking around and trying different combinations in the NSDateFormatter but I just can't seem to find the right one, any help would be appreciated since I know this is something simple that I'm overlooking but I just can't find it.

Comment: Try hh instead of HH for the format, according to http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns (haven't tested yet).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HH stands for 24hr.

hh satnds for 12 hr.

Change accordingly.

Comment: I knew it was something simple like this that I wasn't looking at. Although this is correct to get the 12 hour format, it looks like the formatter is not taking using the offset as well, so the example above is showing as 6:15PM instead of 10:15AM. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the time format using HH which 24 hours format, in order to set for 12 hours format use the following code, although did not have to write much, as code line says all.

```
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

in order to avoid time zone issues, make sure you set the timezone for the formatter as well

```
[timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CET"]];
```

Comment: A bit terse... Please edit the answer and tell what this does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `hh`, not `HH`. The former is for 12-hour, the latter is for 24-hour.