# Incorrect time in Date from 12-Hr format Time String - Swift

Tags: swift, date, time, nsdateformatter

I have following strings as 12-Hr format time:

```
let timeFrom = "05:30 AM";
let timeTo = "04:35 PM";
```

And trying to get date from these for comparison as follows:

```
let openTime = timeFrom.date(format: "hh:mm a")
let closeTime = timeTo.date(format: "hh:mm a")
```

With this extension :

```
extension String
{
    func date(format:String) -> Date?
    {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        return formatter .date(from: self)
    }
}
```

When I print openTime and closeTime, I'm getting incorrect values in time:

```
print(openTime)      // 2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
print(closeTime)     // 2000-01-01 11:00:00 +0000
```

Why this is so ? I think it is smoething related to time zone, so I visit [NSDateFormatter return wrong date + Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407599/nsdateformatter-return-wrong-date-swift), but nothing worked for me. If anybody have the solution, please help me. Thank you !

Comment: Find out the difference between "hh" and "HH."

Comment: oops .. There should be 'hh'. Thanks for pointing out @el Tomato. Checking ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display just the 12 Hour Time format from an ISO 8601 Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121065/display-just-the-12-hour-time-format-from-an-iso-8601-timestamp) and many others.

Comment: @rmaddy: I've asked string to date for incorrect time. And the duplicate link is about string to string with formatting. You must have look at both questions properly.

Comment: What are the results that you expect to see?

Comment: Well, I've just changed timezone as : `formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") as! TimeZone` and there I got expected time : **2000-01-01 05:30:00 +0000** for 5:30 AM and **2000-01-01 16:30:00 +0000** for 04:30 PM. Thank you for your halp ! @El

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I check with swift 3 and Xcode 8 with small changes its working please check

```
 let timeFrom = "05:30 AM";
 let timeTo = "04:35 PM";
 let openTime = timeFrom.date(format: "hh:mm a")
 let closeTime = timeTo.date(format: "hh:mm a")
    
 print(openTime)
 print(closeTime)
```

and make change in extension

```
extension String{
func date(format:String) -> Date?
{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    //formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current //or autoupdatingCurrent
    return formatter .date(from: self)
}}
```

Comment: Yea, I tried changing "GMT+0:00" to "GMT" only and that worked. Thank you !

Comment: @AkshayGajarlawar if working then please accept my answer thank You!

Comment: I don't understand the reason but this work for me!! After 4 hours looking for the solution I just can say Thank you very much!!!